# Computation of Sobolev norm.

Tags: notation, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I want to compute the Sobolev norm $H^2([0,1]^2)$ for a 2d function such as $f(x,y)=x^{10}y^5$. I am confused whether it is,

$$\|f\|_{H^2}^2=\|f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\partial_x f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\partial_y f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\partial^2_{xx} f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\partial^2_{yy} f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\partial^2_{xy} f\|_{L^2}^2$$

or is it,

$$\|f\|_{H^2}^2=\|f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\partial_x f+\partial_y f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\partial^2_{xx} f+\partial^2_{xy} f+\partial^2_{yy} f\|_{L^2}^2$$

Thank you for any help. If both of them are wrong, then what is the right answer? I am confused with the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think its neither, one usually has all elements of the Hessian, and you're missing
$ \partial_y\partial_x f$.
In snappy multi-indices notation , one writes
$$\|f\|^2_{H^2} = \sum_{0\le \alpha\le 2} \|D^\alpha f\|^2_{L^2}$$  though at times it is convenient to use the equivalence of norms on finite dimensional vector spaces to write e.g. $$ \pmb|f\pmb|_{H^2} = \sum_{0\le \alpha\le 2} \|D^\alpha f\|_{L^2}$$
Here $\alpha$ runs through the multiindices $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,0),(0,2)$. One easily checks that $\pmb| {\pmb|}{}_{H^2}$ and $\| \|_{H^2}$ are equivalent norms on $ H^2$.

Regarding your second choice for the norm, which I'll write $|\!|\!|f|\!|\!|$,  if you add this remaining Hessian term and consider a function $g\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ and let $f$ be defined by 
$$f(x,y) = g(x-y)$$
then $f\in L^2([0,1]^2)$, and
$$ \partial_x f + \partial_y f = 0$$
$$ \partial_{x}^2 f + 2\partial_x\partial_y f + \partial_y^2 f = 0$$
I think it should be possible to use this to create a function $f\notin H^2$ such that $|\!|\!|f|\!|\!| = \|f\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am still confused. So how would one compute the sobolev norm of a function $f(x,y)$. Could you please give me an example of some reference. I cannot find a worked out example.

Comment: In my example $\partial^2_{xy}=\partial_x\partial_y$. Since the derivative operator commutes i should have a 2 next to $\partial^2_{xy}$ in the first norm that I defined. I think with the 2 the first norm i stated is the correct one. Can you please confirm?

Comment: @CuriousCat 1. which part of $\|f\|^2_{H^2} = \sum_{0\le \alpha\le 2} \|D^\alpha f\|^2_{L^2}$ do you not understand? Its a sum of 6 things, i listed the specific multi-indices. 2. That's correct but I had to think a little because its not true that $\partial_x \partial_y f = \partial_y \partial_x f$ everywhere for all functions for which these symbols are defined

Comment: Thanks I understand now. Was a bit confused and wanted a confirmation.

Comment: @CuriousCat OK, glad to help. PS its not easy to find a worked example because I think people only care about the exact value when actually implementing these in a computer for some numerics, and in other cases its enough to know if its finite, or infinite. In your example its clearly finite because all derivatives belong to $L^\infty([0,1]^2) \subset L^2$.